# Is there a way to write to a BLOB field in PL/SQL from multiple procedures in parallel (i.e. without locking the row)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to implement chunked file uploads via a restful service, but I'm incurring some overhead getting the separate parts into a single file.

I am using dbms_lob.copy to write each part as it comes in, but I'm wondering if there is still room for improvement, as each chunk is written one at a time.

Here is a snippet of my procedure below:

```
begin
  insert into documents
    (uuid,blob_content,last_updated) 
  values  
    (v_uuid,empty_blob(),sysdate)
  returning blob_content into v_concat_blob
    ;
exception when others then --primary key violation
  update documents 
    set last_updated = sysdate
  where uuid = v_uuid
  returning blob_content into v_concat_blob
    ;
end;

dbms_lob.copy(v_concat_blob,v_blob_chunk,dbms_lob.getlength(v_blob_chunk),v_offset);
commit;
```

Comment: No, you can't. You can however have multiple sessions working on different rows and improve your throughput that way.